# Find $W:= \frac{xy}{z}+\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y} \rightarrow \inf$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I've got two similar problems:

Find

\begin{align} 
&W:= \frac{xy}{z}+\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y} \rightarrow \inf \\
&x + y + z = 1 \\
&x, y, z > 0
\end{align}
and
\begin{align} 
&W:= \frac{xy}{z}+\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y} \rightarrow \inf \\
&x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \\
&x, y, z > 0
\end{align}
I got simple solutions for both of them, but i want to be sure i'm right:
$\dfrac{xy}{z}+\dfrac{yz}{x}+\dfrac{xz}{y} = \dfrac{xy}{2z}+\dfrac{yz}{2x}+\dfrac{xz}{2y} + \dfrac{xy}{2z}+\dfrac{yz}{2x}+\dfrac{xz}{2y} \overset{AM-GM}{\ge} \sqrt{y^2} + \sqrt{x^2} + \sqrt{z^2} = x + y + z.$

For the first problem $\inf$ has to be $1$. For the second problem second constrain defines the sphere, which infimum is in $(0, 0, 0)$ point. 
So answers are $1$ and $0$. Am i right?

**UPD:** I'm definetly not right with the second problem.

Comment: For the second, the point $(0,0,0)$ doesn't lie on the sphere. And you're right, $0$ is not (cannot be) a minimum.

Comment: @user376343 i have no ideas how to solve it. Maybe use spherical coordinates, but after that i'm stucked.